# OSX Brew Python "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopencv"

Tags: python, macos, opencv, pip, homebrew

I'm attempting to install pyopencv. I have installed both Python and OpenCV through Brew. A quick `which python/pip` shows that I'm using the version of Python installed through Brew as the default. I have already installed numpy through pip. However, when I try to run `pip install pyopencv` I get back:

```
Downloading/unpacking pyopencv
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyopencv (from versions: 2.0.wr1.0.1-demo, 2.0.wr1.0.1, 2.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.0, 2.1.0.wr1.0.1, 2.1.0.wr1.0.2, 2.1.0.wr1.1.0, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0-demo, 2.1.0.wr1.2.0)
Cleaning up...
No distributions matching the version for pyopencv
Storing complete log in /Users/golmschenk/.pip/pip.log
```

[A semi-related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19155603/can-opencv-be-installed-in-python-virtualenv-on-mac-mountain-lion) had the same error, but under a different circumstance. The problem here appears to have been with the virtual-environment and they were using the pre-installed version of Python rather than the Brew version.

Any suggestions as to how I might fix this? Thank you much!

**Update:**

According to [this question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18230956/could-not-find-a-version-that-satisfies-the-requirement-pytz) when a `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement` error arises, it's because

> pip will only install stable versions as specified by PEP426 by
>   default. If a version cannot be parsed as a compliant PEP426 version
>   then it is assumed to be a pre-release.

This can be worked around using `pip install --pre` to install pre-release packages. However, upon doing this (or attempting to install pyopencv using easy_install) I run into the error: `ImportError: cannot import name Library`.

**Update 2:**

Further research into this new error presented [this question/solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18981869/install-pyopencv-with-pip-on-mac-os-x). Here the `ImportError: cannot import name Library` comes from the new version of setuptools having the Library is inside of extension.py. Such that pyopencv should import Library as setuptools.extension.Library and not setuptools.Library. A temporary solution to this would be to manually change this. However, I'd prefer a more appropriate solution if one exists over manually editing 3rd-party packages. Any suggestions? Thanks!

**Update 3:**

If OpenCV and Python were install correctly through Brew it appears you can use OpenCV in Python simply by importing the cv2 module (as was discovered in the comments). So that solves my problem. However, for others who may actually need pyopencv for something I'll leave this question open.

Comment: Is there a special reason you want to use pyopencv instead of cv2? Not trying to avoid the question - I don't have a direct solution. It's just that I've only had one situation (Python 3 with OpenCV 1.0) in my limited experience where ctypes_opencv / pyopencv made sense for me.

Comment: Oh look at that. You can use OpenCV in Python simply by importing cv2, eh? Well, that makes my life easier then. Thanks! I'll leave the question open though, just in case others need it.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on my Fedora20, when using fresh virtualenvironment it's not possible to 'import cv2'. And installing pyopencv is causing exactly the same error as you mention. A bit stuck  right now but when I find solution I will post it here.

Comment: For me solution was those two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592389/is-it-possible-to-run-opencv-python-binding-from-a-virtualenv and https://github.com/sightmachine/SimpleCV/issues/647

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Non-answer answer that seemed to work :)

`import cv2`

Anywhere in [the docs](http://docs.opencv.org/) that uses the "new" type interface is talking about the C++ (cv2 in python) interface.

Comment: This works for me (and actually seems like the more appropriate way to do this). However, if someone comes up with the answer for the problem as specified, please leave it here and I'll be happy to move the accept (although this answer at least deserves the +1).